# Truncated incorrect date value mystery

Tags: python, mysql

I am querying a MySQL database via Python and getting a strange behaviour.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE local_time >= CURDATE()
```

The bash then outputs for following warning messages for several items.

```
Warning: Truncated incorrect date value: '2012-12-31T21:00:00-0500'
```

The data is stored as UTF-8 VARCHAR 255 characters. I've checked out the items involved and I can't see any difference between the warning ones and ones that don't give a warning. Am I missing something?

EDIT: I fixed it with the following code:

```
SELECT id FROM table where STR_TO_DATE(left(p.local_time,10), '%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE()
```

However, I still don't understand why this affected some items and not others.

Comment: Simple: bad data AND bad data type. Show us the ones that don't produce warnings?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert it first.

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(left(p.local_time,10), '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work. Only a few warnings come up (20 from a database of 100,000). At least through my Sequel Pro viewer the fields are identical to other items.

Comment: Fixed it! STR_TO_DATE(left(p.local_time,10), '%Y-%m-%d'). You certainly pointed me in the right direction - thanks mate! I still don't know why it only affected certain items not others... a mystery!

Comment: Nice :) I'll change my answer so that others can use it too.